# Python examples of how to use waiter function on AWS SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use the waiter functionality available for SQS on AWS. However, I have not seen any documentation and python examples of this works

AWS Boto / SQS documentation link referring to Waiter here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters, but does not give any detailed examples using SQS

Any guidance appreciated

Comment: I am currently doing this without any waiter functions defined. My questions are around
(1) How is a Waiter defined? Any examples showing this with SQS
(2) Is there any benefit to using waiter function instead of a while loop polling every 60 seconds?

MY CODE BELOW:

import boto3
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='test')
while 1:
    messages = queue.receive_messages(WaitTimeSeconds=60)
    for message in messages:
        print("Message received: {0}".format(message.body))
        message.delete()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you're looking for a high level way to listen to SQS queues from Python code:

[multi_sqs_listener](https://github.com/fvinas/multi_sqs_listener) may help you achieve this (disclosure: I'm the author):

```
from multi_sqs_listener import QueueConfig, EventBus, MultiSQSListener

class MyListener(MultiSQSListener):
    def handle_message(self, queue, bus, priority, message):
        # This is where your actual event handler code will sit
        print(message.body)

my_event_bus = EventBus()
EventBus.register_buses([my_event_bus])

my_queue = QueueConfig('my-queue', my_event_bus)
my_listener = MyListener([my_queue])
my_listener.listen()
```

Answer (score 5):

SQS does not have waiters in boto3.

> Note if a client does not have any waiters, it will return an empty list when accessing its waiter_names attribute.

```
import boto3
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
sqs.waiter_names
[]
```

Comment: Thanks Eytan will continue to use the while loop with polling.